# How to split a comma separated string conditionally

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these strings that contain commas (`,`). I want to **only split a string by a comma if that comma isn't used in a number** (e.g thousands separator). Some examples:

- `breakfast 10$, buy new phone 1k , paying bills 1500$` => `breakfast 10$`, `buy new phone 1k`, `paying bills 1500$`
- `3,000,000` => do not split
- `25,000 buy a new car` => do not split
- `lunch, dinner 25$` => `lunch`, `dinner 25$`

I haven't work much with RegExp. What is the proper and elegant way (using JavaScript String.split and RegExp) to do this ?

Comment: Simply split on comma+space instead? Of course, using regex you can also choose opting for lookaround and be more specific about what "used in a number" means for you.

Comment: It has been solved many times, e.g. `/,(?!\d)/` may work. There are other ways, too.

Comment: The *proper* way to do this is to be to force user to add each list item one at a time (click add button, enter item data, see item added to list separated by commas for instance).  Any commas therefore used will be part of the item itself.

Comment: @Neil in my case, user input is arbitrary so we need to handle this ourself. Thanks for your answer though !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**regex**](https://regex101.com/r/nTCbBb/3) with the **[`string#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Description)** method:

```js
var str = "breakfast 10,000$, buy new phone 1k , paying bills 1500$ => breakfast 10$, buy new phone 1k, paying bills 1500$";

console.log(str.split(/,(?![0-9]+\$?)/));
```

Comment: When I wrote `/,(?!\d)/` (=`/,(?![0-9])/`) may work, it means it does not have to work for OP. It won't split `122,34564334,55674222` that OP might want to split.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I updated the regex to take only numbers with `$` into account.

Comment: Ok, but still `/,(?![0-9]+\$?)/` = `/,(?!\d)/`

Comment: Thanks @chsdk and Wiktor Stribiżew for your answers ! I don't know why my question get down votes though, I haven't worked much with RegExp, I tried searching but I didn't find anything similar

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes and the OP says ***only split a string by a comma if that comma isn't used in a number***, so what's wrong here?

Comment: @chsdk Nothing, if it were wrong, I'd downvote. I just mean you overobfuscated it.

Comment: What about that ? **however what it feels like,10000 is a good number what do you say ?**  the only ',' in this bold text should be split. Isn't it ?

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman Well it's not a good number, it's a comma followed by a number so it shouldn't be matched.

Comment: **I will give poor people some money,500 will be given to A, 10,000 will be given to B**  My point is simple **,500** here this comma should be used as a splitter.

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman Thank you for pointing it out, in this case the regex should be just updated like this: [**`/,(?![0-9]+,[0-9]+\$?)/`**](https://regex101.com/r/nTCbBb/4), it will mach it as expected.

Answer (score 1):

here is my code :
use lookbehide, before comma is not number

> (?<=\D),